# PHP and mySQL Delete certain row based on condition after a join possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been able to cross join two tables removing any duplicates, but I was wondering if it was possible to join both tables then remove any rows that have less than 4 teams. If anyone could provide any help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
  $sql = SELECT * FROM club 
    CROSS JOIN team
    WHERE club.cid=team.clubID;
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Aside: If you have a relationship between the tables it should be `INNER JOIN`, not `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: sadly there's no relationship between the tables, all different column names, so only conclusion I could come to was cross join

Comment: The club ID is the relationship.

Comment: they are under different column names though, so how would I go about that?

Comment: `ON cid = clubID` just like your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Do you want to delete from both clubs and teams, or just from clubs?

Comment: thank you so much that worked! Do you by any chance have the way of deleting all the cid that have c03 in the table? My apologies for any easy fixes I'm very new to PHP and mySQL

Comment: or if a rule is needed than a way to delete/not show any clubs with less than 4 teams based on tID

Answer (score 0):

JOIN with a subquery that gets all the clubs with at least 4 teams.

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM clubs AS c
JOIN teams AS t ON c.cid = t.clubID
JOIN (
    SELECT clubID
    FROM teams
    GROUP BY clubID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
) AS tc ON tc.clubID = c.cid
```

Comment: thank you, if I wanted to echo this new table how would I refer to it, as the SQL DB is read only

Comment: I tried your code as the mySQL is read only the DELETE function will not work, is there any way around this?

Comment: So you don't want to delete anything, you just want to select the rows with at least 4 clubs?

Comment: I want to remove the club that has less than 4 teams which is the clubID - C03, or show a list of the teams with 4 or more teams (basically any team that is corresponding to C01 and C02)

Comment: it worked thank you so much, genuinely you are amazing!

Comment: With the resulting table how would we show this on a webpage via an echo statement? Sorry for asking so many questions, I've been stuck on this issue all day

Comment: The same way you show the result of any other query. There are many tutorials on displaying query results in HTML.